# winston logger includes handling uncaught promise rejections in exception handler

Tags: winston

I am learning a set of Node backend tools.  I just added `winston` and `winston-mongodb` logging.  I am hoping someone with more experience with `winston` can clarify whether the uncaught exceptional handler is assumed to also deal with unhandled promises. From the docs, I assumed these were designed as two separate, distinct handlers. In which case, I am rather stuck on a bug.  I cannot find a way to separate out unhandled promise rejections from general uncaught exceptions. I can essentially create a more narrow, duplicate log for only unhandled promises. But those unhandled promises will be included with the uncaught exception logs. I spent some time logging the transports, but I could turn up any obvious reasons in the way I set up the transports for what seems like duplication. I am wondering at this point if this is expected behavior.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When writing both the exception handlers like this:

```
  // log unhandled exceptions.
  exceptionHandlers: [
    new transports.File({
      filename: "./logs/exceptions.log",
    }),
  ],
  
  // log unhandled rejections.
  rejectionHandlers: [
    new transports.File({
      filename: "./logs/rejections.log",
    }),
  ],
```

This caused a *duplicate* entry in the error log, where I believe the expected result is to only have **one** error logged - being either exception or rejection, whichever tripped up.

The **solution** to this for me was to write the exception handlers like this:

```
  transports: [
    new transports.File({
      filename: "./logs/errors.log",
      handleExceptions: true, /* set this option to true */
      handleRejections: true, /* set this option to true */
    }),
  ],
```

This should log both exceptions *and* rejections to the same log file.

Answer (score 0):

When exceptionHandlers is defined alone without rejectionHandlers it's handling both uncaught exceptions and unhandled rejections. though instead of naming unhandled rejections as "unhandledRejection" on the message key, it's naming it "uncaughtException". On the other hand, including rejectionsHandlers without exceptionsHandlers, the rejectionHandlers is not able to catch the uncaughtExceptions. The issue comes when you include both of them to catch the errors on separate files, both exceptionHandlers, and rejectionHandlers will catch both 'uncaughtExceptions' and 'unhandledRejections' on let's say 'rejections.log' file and 'exceptions.log' file and the files will be duplicates of each other.

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require("winston");
require("winston-mongodb");

module.exports = createLogger({
  level: "info",
  format: format.json(),
  transports: [
    new transports.Console(),
    new transports.File({ filename: "logs/logfile.log" }),
    new transports.MongoDB({ db: "db_uri" }),
  ],
  exceptionHandlers: [
    new transports.File({
      filename: "logs/exceptions.log",
    }),
  ],

  rejectionHandlers: [
    new transports.File({
      filename: "logs/rejections.log",
    }),
  ],
  exitOnError: false,
});
```

On the above implementation, the rejections.log and exceptions.log have the exact same content where they are both catching uncaughtExceptions and unhandledRejections.

I'm trying to implement the above case, but its seems like the winston package has a bug.